# What does "correlation" mean in signal processing?

Tags: noise

What do the words "correlated" and "uncorrelated" mean in signal processing? E.g. - "*uncorrelated white noise..*"

Answer (score 13):

What it usually means:

> "**correlation**, *In statistics, the degree of association between two random variables. The correlation between the graphs of two data sets is the degree to which they resemble each other. However, correlation is not the same as causation, and even a very close correlation may be no more than a coincidence. Mathematically, a correlation is expressed by a correlation coefficient that ranges from −1 (never occur together), through 0 (absolutely independent), to 1 (always occur together)."*

*(from [Encyclopedia Brittanica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/690049/correlation))*

Uncorrelated white noise means that no two points in the noise's time domain are associated with each other. You can't predict any noise value at any other time from the noise level at time \$t\$. The correlation coefficient is 0.
Even if you know the noise signal over an eternal time, except for that one picosecond, all this information can't help you to fill in that picosecond's level. That's zero correlation.

Correlation within the signal itself is called autocorrelation.

Comment: The last sentence in the quotation from Encyclopedia Britannica is incorrect in that if the correlation coefficient \$r\$ has value \$\pm 1\$, the two quantities \$X\$ and \$Y\$ are said to be _perfectly (positively or negatively) correlated._ In fact, \$Y = aX+b\$ _exactly_ with \$a>0\$ and \$Y\$ increasing with \$X\$ if \$r=+1\$, and with \$a<0\$ and \$Y\$ decreasing as \$X\$ increases if \$r=-1\$.  For \$0<|r|<1\$, \$Y\approx aX+b\$ with the approximation improving as \$r\$ gets closer to \$1\$, and same relation \$\text{sgn}(a)=\text{sgn}(r)\$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, From the phrase "never occur together", etc., we can imagine that the Brittanica author was writing about  random variables that only take two values indicating occurence or non-occurence of some event.

Comment: @ThePhoton Even restricted to random variables taking on values \$0\$ and \$1\$ only indicating non-occurrence and occurrence respectively, _my_ interpretation of the phrase "never occur together" is that \$P(1,1)=0\$ while \$P(1,0),P(0,1)\$ and \$P(0,0)\$ can be nonzero. However, \$r=-1\$ _only if_ \$P(0,0)\$ _also equals_ \$0\$. That is, when \$r=-1\$, \$P(0,1)\$ and \$P(1,0)\$ _both_ are nonzero (they need not be equal) and \$P(1,1)=P(0,0)=0\$. Equivalently, \$r=-1\$ if and only it always so happens that _exactly one_ of the two random variables has value \$1\$ and the other has value \$0\$

Comment: @DilipSarwate, OK, now I get it, and I agree the Britannica language is not as precise as it could be.

Comment: "Correlation within the signal itself is called autocorrelation"  then  What is cross correlation?

Answer (score 10):

*Uncorrelated white noise* is a pleonasm in the sense that there is **no such thing as correlated white noise.**  One either has white noise which by
definition has certain properties including a lack of correlation,
or one has noise that is correlated and so cannot be described as white
noise in any sense of the phrase.

The mathematical model of continuous-time white noise is a convenient 
fiction that accounts for the physically observed fact that the noise
power spectrum at the output of a filter with transfer function 
\$H(f)\$ is proportional to \$|H(f)|^2\$.  If we pretend that
the input to the filter is white noise -- which has infinite bandwidth, 
and flat power spectrum over this infinite bandwidth 
(and hence infinite power) -- and apply standard random process
theory, we come to the result that the noise at the filter
output is indeed proportional to \$|H(f)|^2\$.  So this 
infinitely powerful mythical beast white noise is a plausible 
explanation for our physically measured results, and thus
white noise is commonly used in theoretical calculations.
One additional property of white noise is that two 
white noise samples are statistically independent 
(and hence uncorrelated) no matter how closely spaced 
they are in time. Of course, one cannot take actual
samples of our mathematical fiction. In real life, all
measurements are made using finite-bandwidth instruments 
(say \$W\$ Hz), and so the noise samples that we
*can* measure are those obtained after some implicit
filtering of the white noise that we set out to sample.
In particular, noise samples less than \$W^{-1}\$ seconds apart definitely
*are* correlated.  Noise samples further apart in time 
also are correlated but the correlation values are small 
enough that it is reasonable to treat them as negligible
and assume that the samples are indeed independent
and uncorrelated.  For more on this viewpoint,
read Appendix A of [this lecture 
note](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/spring11/Newlectures/lecture03.pdf)

If a continuous-time noise process is sampled at the 
Nyquist rate and converted to a discrete-time sequence 
of samples, then each sample can be taken to be
a random variable (usually zero-mean Gaussian)
independent of all other samples.  Thus, a *discrete-time*
white noise process is a sequence of independent
(and hence uncorrelated) identically distributed
zero-mean random variables. If the random variables
are Gaussian (as is almost always assumed), the
process is called a discrete-time white Gaussian
noise process. In any case, it is not necessary to
say *uncorrelated* white noise: white noise is
always uncorrelated.

Answer (score 3):

When 2 signals are said to be *correlated*, it means that their [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) is non zero. The correlation coefficient is a value between -1 and +1, that depends on how the 2 signals vary together. If they vary largely "independently", then the correlation is close to 0 and the signals are said to be uncorrelated. If the correlation coefficient is close to 1, they are strongly correlated and if it is close to -1, they are strongly anti-correlated.

**Auto correlation** of a signal is a series that shows patterns within a signal. Each point of this series is the correlation coefficient of the signal with a delayed (or advanced) version of itself.

**Uncorrelated noise** refers to noise that has a zero autocorrelation function. So, every point in the noise signal is "independent" of every other point. So, even if you have signal values for large time epochs, you cannot predict the next value.

"Whiteness" of a noise refers to the flatness of its power spectrum. It is possible for uncorrelated noise to not be white, but pink(!) or other colors based on the power spectrum.

So, **uncorrelated white noise** is noise that is both uncorrelated and has a flat power spectrum. White [Gaussian noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_noise) is an example of uncorrelated white noise.

Comment: IMO, The Auto-correlation of white noise tends to an impulse, not to a uniformly zero function. Please correct this in your answer. This is  by virtue of Wiener-Khinchin Theorem which states that the autocorrelation function of a wide-sense-stationary random process has a spectral decomposition given by the power spectrum of that process.

Comment: The original question was about correlation with an example of uncorrelated white noise. So, the answer was simply about what is correlated vs uncorrelated, and the meaning of the term "white noise".  The auto correlation of white noise was not the subject of this question, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

As Steven explained, in statistics 2 events are correlated if knowing the outcome of one gives information to predict the outcome of the other one.

For instance, if you throw a coin twice, the statistics say that the two events are ***independent***, and knowing one won't affect the prediction on the other one. But if you have a cards deck, and you pick the ace of spades (without putting it back), you know that's impossible that the next times it will come out again. The events are ***dependent***.

***Correlation*** is somewhat similar: if your wife starts taking *sewing lessons* at 11 pm twice a week, and at the same time your *best friend* is in *business meetings*, you may think that the two events share some properties.

A [stochastic process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) describes the behavior of a stochastic event over time. It means that you can have many different values at any time, and any possible outcome is defined as a function of time. The theory is complicated, but think to it as an immense music library. At any instant, one song of the library will be playing, and you can generate *infinite* playlists. (sorry for the lame example)

In this system, you can have two types of correlations: in **time** and in **state**. The time correlation says that knowing what's played at a certain time, you can predict (to a certain extent) what will be played in a few seconds. The state correlation says that from the same knowledge (what's being played now) you can estimate *what else* could have been played at the same time (maybe it was set for playing rock music at 5 pm).

---

**[Electronic noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_%28electronics%29)** is a very broad term that indicates everything that mixes together with your signal without giving any useful information, and making the useful part less clear. In communications, there is a lot of effort in getting the information to the other side, and this implies making the signal to stand out in the noise. It can be done increasing the power of the signal in transmission, *shielding* the communication medium, filtering or in other ways.

Since noise can be due to different phenomena, it will also have different properties. [Thermal noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_noise) is due to the vibration of charge carriers in conductors, so you can expect it to depend on the temperature of the same; **interference** happens when another signal generator (think to a microwave oven) transmits over your signal. In this last case, if you know what the transmitter is doing, you can counter the effect in a more directed way (for instance, a [band-stop filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-stop_filter) centered at the exact frequency).

So knowing the statistic properties of signal and noise can help in separating the former from the latter, when analysis is necessary.